# Dim screen before screensaver

Tags: x11, xorg, screen-lock, screensaver, dpms

Using [DPMS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling), my screen goes blank after 10 minutes. How would I go about dimming (lowering the backlight) of the screen a few seconds before this happens, as a sort of warning?

Output of `xset -q`:

```
[...]
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  600    cycle:  600
[...]
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 600    Suspend: 600    Off: 600
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimming is done by screensavers (that will also do the blanking without the need for `X11` automatically timed `DPMS` features). Try the configuration options of `xscreensaver` or `gnome-screensaver` or whatever locking program comes with your Desktop (which window manager is it?).  Your window manager may also have this interface in its "Power" (or similar) options.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm running bspwm, so most of my configuration is manual. I've given `xscreensaver` a go, and it seems to be working perfectly.

Comment: I am glad I could help :-)